# How can we add timestamp adjacent to a cell in google spreadsheet using appscript when any user of that sheet edits a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a basic attendance workflow where my users will mark attendance in a google spreadsheet. There are separate worksheet for each month. Column E is where users will mark attendance using their gmail login. Column F will set a timestamp in adjacent cell when value was selected in column E.

I have a workable code but that works only for me. When other users of the sheet add or update value in the Column E, the Column F does not set a timestamp.

Update:
I have protected Column F so that users can't manually edit the timestamp entry.

This is the piece of code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var columnToWatch = 5, columnToStamp = 6; //change all of these to your needs
    if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch ||  !e.value) return;
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
        .getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
        .setValue(new Date());  
}
```

Comment: Is there anything above or below this function?

Comment: @TheMaster could that be because of the sheet protection? according to the OP other users can only edit column E. Maybe the sheets are protected.

Comment: @Marios It could be, but I don't see where OP mentions "others cannot edit anything except E"

Comment: @TheMaster true true. I didn't phrase it correctly. The others might be able to edit only column E. Could OP clarify that for us?

Comment: Alternatively look into view> executions and show the error.

Comment: No @TheMaster there is nothing above or below this function.

Comment: @Marios Yes I will clarify. No there is range protection for Column F, so that users can't edit the timestamp. Column E doesn't have any sheet or range protection.

Comment: Then that explains a lot. The onEdit() function updates the timestamp in column F. If other users can't edit column F how is it possible to be able to update the value? Essentially, you can't update the value of a cell if you don't have the permission to edit it.

Comment: That's true. But how do I restrict users manually updating Timestamp in Column F. I had protected the ranges for the same reason.

Comment: @PulkitJain Read the linked question and answers.. Use installable triggers. Also make sure editors cannot go into the script editor/ edit the script. In which case, they'll easily be able modify your script.